# How to toggle an error message using "ng-show" which only shows when a textarea reaches its maxlength?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

For the text field below, what I aim to do is make it so that the span with class `text-danger` only shows when the text being entered in `textarea` reaches the `maxlength` value.

As I understand it, the angular framework allows `maxlength` or `ng-maxlength` to speak to another html element and trigger an action when that maxlength is reached. How would I go about doing this?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">{{ "Message" | i18next }}</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="40"
            ng-model="emailAsAttachment.message" name="message" 
            placeholder="{{ 'Optional: include a personal message' | i18next}}"
            maxlength="{{MAX_INPUT_LENGTHS.description}}"></textarea>
  <span class="text-danger" id="export-filename-error"
         ng-show="exportForm.message.$invalid">
    {{ "Maximum length of 10,000 characters exceeded." | i18next }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to simultaneously prevent a user from exceeding the maxlength, while also detecting when it's reached.

Use the `maxlength={{MAXLENGTH}}` attribute to prevent the textbox from exceeding the specified length.

Use `ng-show="emailAsAttachment.message.length == MAXLENGTH"` to display that the specified length has been reached.

[THE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KuPe4XBDaZMmjGtmNRdG?p=preview)

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
  <form name="exportForm">  
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="40"
            ng-model="emailAsAttachment.message" name="message" 
            placeholder="Enter 5 or less characters"
            maxlength="5">
  </textarea>
  </form>
  <span class="text-danger" id="export-filename-error"
         ng-show="emailAsAttachment.message.length == 5">
    {{ "Maximum length of 5 characters reached." }}
  </span>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxlength` for validation and to limit the length of the input or `ng-maxlength` only to validation purpose. Then you will have access to `exportForm.message.$error.maxlength`

Comment: Ah makes sense. This approach only seems to work when exceeding the maxlength. Does `$error.maxlength` only detect when the length is exceeded, or is there a way to detect simply when it is reached? I want to simultaneously prevent a user from exceeding the maxlength, while also detecting when it's reached.